# ReactJS " io is not defined" using CDN link of SOCKET IO

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, socket.io, cdn

I do not want to use Npm package for my project So i try to use CDN link to use SOCKET IO in client side .

Please Note that same CDN link is working fine in normal html/css js but not in react project.

I put CDN link index.html inside Pubic folder of React project

here it is:

```
<script defer src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.min.js"  integrity="sha384-cPwlPLvBTa3sKAgddT6krw0cJat7egBga3DJepJyrLl4Q9/5WLra3rrnMcyTyOnh" crossorigin="anonymous" ></script>
```

Thanks in Advance

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:3000/");
```

I put this constant before class component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `React Hook` which uses a `React useEffect` that just uses Javascript to query select the `head` component and create a script element to manually set the `src`.

Or you could use a library like [React Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) which lets you handle `script` injection easily within `React` without needing to install the module.

**EDIT***

The absolute bare-bones way to access the `io` methods in `React` if you are using placing the `script` inside `/public/index.html` is:

`const socket = window.io();`

Comment: but what is the need to this I mean I have already paste the script tag in the head element with defer tag and its executing just Io does not get detect.

Comment: Oh I see. Well if you `console.log(window);` you should see `io` as an accessible property.